# Multisite loads assets from main site

Tags: multisite

I have two sites with completely different domain names, recently moved to https, and I've switched to nginx. My issue is that my secondary blog is trying to load assets from the main site's URL and it's breaking because of CORS. I've tried updating every instance of the url in the DB via search and replace, however there's nothing left but the new url, yet despite that the  assets still load from the other URL.

[image: WP correctly loads it's scripts, but all the CSS loaded from the theme don't]

Comment: Perhaps a cache issue?

Comment: when you moved to https, how did you do that? and are you calling `switch_to_blog` anywhere? Have you modified `wp-config.php`?

Comment: Also, did you update .htaccess with the network settings?

Comment: Q – It's not a cache issue, I delete the file, and it gets automatically regenerated, and called via the wrong domain. Tom – I'm not aware of the switch_to_blog command, I'll dive into that. deronimo – it's nginx not apache